# Passing a variable path to background image

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material

```
let clientTypeId = this.localStorageService.get("ClientApplication");   
 if(clientTypeId !=null) {
     this.SummaryMapFullImage = Constants.SUMMARYMAPFULLIMAGEPATH + clientTypeId + '/' + Constants.SUMMARYMAPFULLIMAGE;    
}    
$('.summary-img').css('background-image', 'url(+this.SummaryMapFullImage+)');
```

**this.SummaryMapFullImage** has image path, I need to pass this to background URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including "this.SummaryMapFullImage" as part of your string rather than evaluating it as a variable.  Also you're missing double-quotes around your URL. Changing your `css()` call to this would solve that:

```
$('summary-img').css('background-image', 'url("' + this.SummaryMapFullImage + '")');
```

Or you could use single-quotes around the URL, but then you'd have to escape them:

```
$('summary-img').css('background-image', 'url(\'' + this.SummaryMapFullImage + '\')');
```

Either way, now, if `this.SummaryMapFullImage` is "https://somedomain.com/img.ext", then you'll be setting `background-image` to something like `url('https://somedomain.com/img.ext')`, which seems to be what you want.